# How to use TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc in linq to sql?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datacontext

I have an user table called zeekuser in which I am storing Time Zone information related to user. while retrieving I using below code,

```
var v = (from s in dc.UserWebSites
                             join zk in dc.ZeekUsers on s.aspnet_User.UserId equals zk.UserId
                             where s.aspnet_User.LoweredUserName.Equals(strUsername.ToLower())
                             select new UserWebSiteInfo
                             {
                                 CreateDt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(s.CreateDt, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(zk.TimeZoneID)),
                                 LastUpdateDt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(s.LastUpdate, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(zk.TimeZoneID)),
                                 LogoImage = s.LogoImage,
                                 Nickname = s.Nickname,
                                 Title1 = s.Title1,
                                 Title2 = s.Title2,
                                 SiteID = s.SiteID.ToString(),
                                 TemplateID = s.TemplateID.ToString(),
                                 TemplateName = s.WebSiteTemplate.ThemeName,
                                 IsActive = s.IsActive,
                                 IsRedirect = s.IsRedirect,
                                 RedirectURL = s.RedirectURL,
                                 UPID = s.UPID.ToString(),
                                 UserId = s.aspnet_User.UserId.ToString(),
                                 Username = s.aspnet_User.UserName,
                                 UserProductName = s.UserProductDetail.Nickname,
                                 PageCount = s.UserWebSitePages.Count(),
                                 AuthorName = s.AuthorName,
                                 AuthorURL = s.AuthorURL
                             }).OrderByDescending(y => y.LastUpdateDt);
                    info = v.ToList();
```

but I am getting below error

Method 'System.TimeZoneInfo FindSystemTimeZoneById(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.

Each different user can have different time zones. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You need to do that on the client, not the server.

Comment: The method does not have an SQL method so you cannot do it within the call to the database, but have to do the conversion on the result.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen the time zone information is in table. So how can I achieve this in case there are multiple records are returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that you can do that within the query that's sent to SQL Server. Instead, use `AsEnumerable` to change context to perform the final step on the .NET side:

```
var query = from s in dc.UserWebSites
            join zk in dc.ZeekUsers on s.aspnet_User.UserId equals zk.UserId
            where s.aspnet_User.LoweredUserName.Equals(strUsername.ToLower())
            orderby s.LastUpdate descending
            select new { Site = s, ZoneId = zk.TimeZoneID };

// Do the rest of the query in-process, so we can use time zones.
var results = (from pair in query.AsEnumerable()
               let site = pair.Site
               let zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(pair.ZoneId)
               select new UserWebSiteInfo {
                   // Select all your properties here
               }).ToList();
```

This is assuming that there's not much more information in `UserWebSites` than you'll be using to construct the `UserWebSiteInfo`; if there *is* a load of information which is irrelevant, you should select the relevant parts explicitly in your initial db-side query.

Comment: Thanks for quick solution. Due to this will there be any performance issues?

Comment: @PratikGaikwad: Well it'll be performing the transformation within .NET, but that shouldn't be too costly. The *filtering* will still occur at the database.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Hey Jon, what's about filtering, i need to filter by date, and i have issue with timezone, i guess performance will be bad in this case, when it comes to 100 000 entities?

Comment: @ValentynVynogradskiy: I think you should ask a new question with more context. "I have issue with time zone" really doesn't explain the situation enough for anyone to help you.